# Building a parser in prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am trying to build a parser but I can't seem to understand how it works. I need help with someone pointing me in the right direction so I can pick it up from there.

SO I have a tokenizer and a lexer.

Tokenizer output:

[int,add,(,int,a,,,int,b,),=,a,+,b,int,letin,(,int,a,),=,let,b,=,10,in,add,(,a,,,b,),int,equal,(,int,a,,,int,b,),=,if,a,==,b,then,letin,(,a,),else,1,int,main,(,int,input,),=,equal,(,input,,,2,)]

Lexer Output:

[TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,OPEN_P,TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,COMMA,TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,CLOSE_P,ASSIGN,IDENTIFIER,ARITH_ADD,IDENTIFIER,TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,OPEN_P,TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,CLOSE_P,ASSIGN,LET,IDENTIFIER,ASSIGN,IDENTIFIER,LET_IN,IDENTIFIER,OPEN_P,IDENTIFIER,COMMA,IDENTIFIER,CLOSE_P,TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,OPEN_P,TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,COMMA,TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,CLOSE_P,ASSIGN,COND_IF,IDENTIFIER,LOGIC_EQ,IDENTIFIER,COND_THEN,IDENTIFIER,OPEN_P,IDENTIFIER,CLOSE_P,COND_ELSE,INTEGER,TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,OPEN_P,TYPE_INT,IDENTIFIER,CLOSE_P,ASSIGN,IDENTIFIER,OPEN_P,IDENTIFIER,COMMA,INTEGER,CLOSE_P]

Now I have to build a parser. I don't get how to start and how to include parameterized constructs.

My rules are to be something like this.

```
program --> functionList.
functionList --> function,functionListCollection.
functionListCollection --> functionList | [].
function --> typeID(typeIdList),[=],expression.
typeID --> [int],[id] | [bool],[id].
typeIdList --> typeID,typeIdListCollection.
typeIdListCollection --> [,], typeIdList | [].
expression --> [if], comparison, [then], value, [else], value.
expression --> [let],[id],[=], value, [in], expression.
expression --> value, extraExpression.
extraExpression --> arithmetic | [].
arithmetic --> [+], value | [-], value.
comparison --> value, comparisonRight.
comparisonRight --> [=],[=],value.
comparisonRight --> [!], [=], value.
comparisonRight --> [>], value.
comparisonRight --> [>], [=], value.
value --> [number].
value --> [id], valueParameters.
valueParameters --> [(],parameters,[)]. | [].
parameters --> value, parametersList.
parametersList --> [,], parameters | [].
```

I am looking a build a predicate that takes the lexed list and gives the list out of the parser. I will then replace the numbers and identifiers by looking at the token list. Some help on how to start would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your 'Lexer Output' seems not only useless, but actually dangerous. It (arbitrarly?) renames important symbols (like `int`) that are already part of the parser (btw, tokenizer and lexer are **synonyms** afaik). So, just feed your DCG (once corrected, see below) with tokenizer output:

```
tokens_test :-
    Tokens = [
        int,add,=,a,+,33
        % ...more source code to test - but please use writeq to show it  ...
        %,int,let,in,'(',int,a,')',=,let,b,=,10
        %,in,add,'(',a,',',b,')',int,equal,'(',int,a,',',int,b,')',=
        %,if,a,==,b,then,let,in,'(',a,')',else,1
        %,int,main,'(',int,input,')',=,equal,'(',input,',',2,')'
    ], phrase(program, Tokens).

?- tokens_test.
true
```

I changed your DCG, since you had [id] and [number] as terminals:

```
id --> [I], {atom(I)}.
number --> [N], {number(N)}.

program --> functionList.
functionList --> function,functionListCollection.
functionListCollection --> functionList | [].
function --> typeID,[=],expression.
typeID --> [int],id | [bool],id.
typeIdList --> typeID,typeIdListCollection.
typeIdListCollection --> [,], typeIdList | [].
expression --> [if], comparison, [then], value, [else], value.
expression --> [let], id, [=], value, [in], expression.
expression --> value, extraExpression.
extraExpression --> arithmetic | [].
arithmetic --> [+], value | [-], value.
comparison --> value, comparisonRight.
comparisonRight --> [=],[=],value.
comparisonRight --> [!], [=], value.
comparisonRight --> [>], value.
comparisonRight --> [>], [=], value.
value --> number.
value --> id, valueParameters.
valueParameters --> ['('],parameters,[')'] | [].
parameters --> value, parametersList.
parametersList --> [,], parameters | [].
```

Where you have a separator (the comma, below), you can avoid service predicates like

```
typeIdList --> typeID,typeIdListCollection.
typeIdListCollection --> [,], typeIdList | [].
```

that could be

```
typeIdList --> typeID, ( [,], typeIdList | [] ).
```

but the convenience of this 'simplification' could depends on other factors.

> how to include parameterized constructs

id//0 and number//0 are non terminals that should 'get back' their value: they become id//1 and number//1, and conventionally, we used to 'tag' the value with the non terminal (so we spare symbols :-)

```
id(id(I)) --> [I],   % better to filter out keywords here...
  {atom(I), \+memberchk(I,[let, etc etc])}.
number(number(N,integer)) --> [N], {integer(N)}.
number(number(N,float)) --> [N], {float(N)}.
```

now where they are called, we must change to

```
...
typeID --> [int],id(_) | [bool],id(_).
...
```

it's obvious that typeID//0 now should 'get back' the values (so called semantic attributes), otherwise they are lost:

```
...
typeID(typeID(T,I)) --> [int],id(I),{T=int} | [bool],id(I),{T=bool}.
...
```

that shows a better way to write typeID//1. Could be

```
typeID(typeID(T,I)) --> type(T),id(I).

type(int) --> [int].
type(bool) --> [bool].
```

Hope you get the picture :-)

Answer (score 1):

make your lexer (*) output for you, instead, data as

```
[type(int), id(add), open_p, type(int), id(a), .....
```

so you have full information in your rules, like

```
....
typeID(T,A) --> [type(T)], { memberchk(T, [int,bool]) }, [id(A)],
....
```

Testing:

```
32 ?- phrase( typeID(X,Y), [type(int), id(i)], []).
X = int,
Y = i.

33 ?- phrase( typeID(X,Y), [type(bool), id(i)], []).
X = bool,
Y = i.

34 ?- phrase( typeID(X,Y), [type(float), id(i)], []).
false.
```

(*) Or you can just combine your tokens and your current lexer output to get the combined data, with `maplist`.